# how to access all public variables in the class sequentially?

Tags: c#, reflection, variables

I want to access all public variables declared in the class sequentially.
Which is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
FieldInfo [] fields = typeof(YourClass).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

this will return FieldInfo on all the public fields

Comment: Tip: You might need (BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); if the class is not static.

Answer (score 0):

```
typeof(MyClass).GetMembers()
```

Comment: He just wants the public _variables_, not the methods and functions.